# Compile a code evaluating a condition only if another condition is positive

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile

Consider the following three tables:

```
thzrange = 
  Flatten[Table[{-Pi + i*0.1, 40 + j*1}, {i, 0, 20, 1}, {j, 0, 30, 
     1}], {1, 2}];
phrange = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, 10^4];
Exrange = Table[Ex, {Ex, 5, 100, 5}];
```

Using their elements, one may obtain values of some functions:

```
coord1[th_, z_, ph_] = z*Cos[th]*Sin[ph];
coord2[Ex_, th_, z_, ph_] = Ex*Exp[-z/50]*Cos[th]^2*Sin[ph]^5;
```

I would like to obtain the following table:

`{Ex,th,z,acc1,acc2}`

where `acc1,acc2` are some acceptances depending on `Ex,th,z` (boolean conditions on correspondingly `coord1,coord2`) that are averaged over values of `phrange`. Moreover, `acc2` may be non-zero (i.e., starts evaluating) only if `acc1` is non-zero. The test conditions are

```
condition1[x1_] = Boole[-5 < x1 < 5];
condition2[x2_] = Boole[-15 < x2 < 0];
```

where x1, x2 are the values of `coord1` and `coord2`.In reality, they may be much more complicated.

So this is my code: `AccComp` which computes the acceptances `acc1`, `acc2` for `k`th combination of `th,z` and `l`th value of `Ex`:

```
AccComp = 
  Hold@Compile[{{thzrange, _Real, 2}, {phrange, _Real, 
           1}, {Exrange, _Real, 1}, {k, _Integer}, {l, _Integer}}, 
         Module[{x1val, x2val, thval, zval, Exval, phval, acc1v, acc1,
            acc2, acc2counter, xproj1val},
          acc1 = 0;
          acc2 = 0.;
          acc2counter = 0;
          Do[
           phval = Compile`GetElement[phrange, m];
           thval = Compile`GetElement[thzrange, k, 1];
           zval = Compile`GetElement[thzrange, k, 2];
           x1val = coord1[thval, zval, phval];
           acc1v = condition1[x1val];
           acc1 += acc1v;
           If[acc1v == 1,
            Exval = Exrange[[l]];
            acc2counter += 1;
            x2val = coord2[Exval, thval, zval, phval];
            acc2 += condition2[x2val];
            ], {m, 1, Length[phrange], 1}];
          {acc1/Length[phrange], 
           If[acc2counter != 0, acc2/acc2counter, 0]}], 
         CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
       DownValues@coord1 /. DownValues@coord2 /. 
     DownValues@condition1 /. DownValues@condition2 // ReleaseHold;
```

and the final table:

```
thzExtable = 
  Flatten[Table[{Exrange[[l]],thzrange[[k]][[1]], thzrange[[k]][[2]]},{l, 1, 
     Length[Exrange], 1}, {k, 1, Length[thzrange], 1}], {1, 2}];
tableaccvalsComp = 
 Hold@Compile[{{thzrange, _Real, 2}, {phrange, _Real, 
       1}, {Exrange, _Real, 1}}, 
     Table[AccComp[thzrange, phrange, Exrange, k, l],{l, 1, Length[Exrange], 1}, {k, 1, 
       Length[thzrange], 1}], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   DownValues@AccComp // ReleaseHold
```

It is not fast:

```
Join[thzExtable, 
   Flatten[tableaccvalsComp[thzrange, phrange, Exrange], {1, 2}], 
   2]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.48617,Null}

Could you please tell me how to optimize it further?

Comment: What your remark "In reality, they may be much more complicated" means?

Comment: @AlexTrounev : it may be expressed in terms of some function of x1, x2.

Comment: If we can optimize your current code then it is not means that it gonna be optimized for your more complicated expressions.

Comment: @AlexTrounev : I am looking rather for a direction of the optimization. The code above just serves as a toy example.

Comment: What makes you think this can be improved? The computation contains only simple  functions, so unless you go into extreme C-level optimizations (at which point you should probably just write C code), you'll need some algorithm-level optimizations (which at some point depends on the exact problem at hand and might not be solvable using only a toy problem). One thing that appears to give a factor of 2 at least is to compute `Sin[phrange]` and `MapAt[Cos,thzrange,{All,1}]`, and pass that in instead of computing `Sin[ph]` and `Cos[th]` every time.

Comment: @LukasLang : the toy task I implemented here captures some of the general features of the realistic task I am dealing with, so I expect that I would be able to adapt any algorithm optimizations to the realistic task. "One thing that appears to give a factor of 2" - such speedup is also very crucial for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the random sampling of $\phi$ completely by computing the limits of the acceptable $\phi$ values. For this, we can use that your expressions only depend on a factor $ain\phi$, which is monotonous in $\phi$ over $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ (values outside that interval don't matter, since $\sin\phi$ is simply mirrored at $\pm\pi/2$. The nested condition for `x2` corresponds then simply to the intersection of the respective intervals.

Below the code for this "analytic approach". Note that I set `phrange` to include `10^5` values for better sampling of the original version of the code (this variable is not used in the new version):

```
thzrange = 
  Flatten[Table[{-Pi + i*0.1, 40 + j*1}, {i, 0, 20, 1}, {j, 0, 30, 
     1}], {1, 2}];
phrange = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, 10^5];
Exrange = Table[Ex, {Ex, 5, 100, 20}];

thzExtable = 
  Flatten[Table[{Exrange[[l]], thzrange[[k]][[1]], 
     thzrange[[k]][[2]]}, {l, 1, Length[Exrange], 1}, {k, 1, 
     Length[thzrange], 1}], {1, 2}];

tableaccvals[thzrange_, Exrange_] :=
 Module[{thval, zval, x1fac, int1, x2fac, int2},
  Transpose@Table[
    thval = thzrange[[k, 1]];
    zval = thzrange[[k, 2]];
    x1fac = zval Cos[thval];
    int1 = If[x1fac == 0,
      {-\[Pi]/2., \[Pi]/2.},
      Sort@N@ArcSin@Clip[{-5., 5.}/zval/Cos[thval]]
      ];
    Table[
     x2fac = E^(-zval/50) Exrange[[l]] Cos[thval]^2;
     int2 = If[x2fac == 0,
       {-\[Pi]/2., \[Pi]/2.},
       Sort@N@ArcSin@Clip[Surd[{0., -15.}/x2fac, 5]]
       ];
     {-Subtract @@ int1/Pi
      , If[-Subtract @@ int1 != 0, (
       Min[int1[[2]], int2[[2]]] - 
        Max[int1[[1]], int2[[1]]])/-Subtract @@ int1, 0]},
     {l, Length[Exrange]}
     ],
    {k, Length[thzrange]}
    ]
  ]

cresult = 
   Join[thzExtable, 
    Flatten[tableaccvalsComp[thzrange, phrangeL, Exrange], {1, 2}], 
    2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {8.95623, Null} *)

aresult = 
   Join[thzExtable, Flatten[tableaccvals[thzrange, Exrange], {1, 2}], 
    2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0897391, Null} *)

Max@Abs[aresult - cresult]
(* 0.00756831 *)
```

Note the 100x speedup, while simulatenously improving the accuracy of the result (the error will get smaller if you increase the number of `ph` samples, and thus runtime, of the original version)